# Conditions and for loop in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am trying to solve a population algorithm.

These are the conditions:

- the starting population is 26000
- Influx of people each year is set in a variable
- Emigrated people each year is set in a variable
- Born each year are 0.7% of the population
- Deceased year are 0.8% of the population

The user provides the year when this algorithm ends.

1. Then there a summary should state if there is a increase of decrease that has occurred and the number of either increased or decreased.
2. Each line should then show the year and the population for that year until the end year provided by the user.

In my code I have set the end year to 2030 from readline and influx variable to 300, and emigrated variable to 325. But depending on these values, there could either be a increase or decrease each year, this value is static for each year.

Below is my code:

```
using System;

namespace algoritmer.loopsFor
{
    public class Övn38
    {

        int Population = 26000;
        int TotalPopulation;
        int influx = 300;
        int emigrated = 325;

        public void CalcPopulation(int endYear)
        {
            int born = (int)(0.007 * Population);
            int deceased = (int)(0.006 * Population);
            Population = influx - emigrated + born + deceased;

            if (Population > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Current Population increases each year  by: {Population}");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine($"Current Population decreases each year by: {Population}");

            Console.WriteLine("__________________________________________");

            for (int startYear = 2019+1; startYear <= endYear; startYear++)
            {
                Population = Population + influx - emigrated + born - deceased;
                TotalPopulation = Population + Population;
                Console.WriteLine($"Population for year {startYear} is: {TotalPopulation}");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("__________________________________________");
        }

        public void printCalcPopulation()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Population is: {Population}");
            Console.WriteLine("Write the end year");
            int year = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("__________________________________________");
            CalcPopulation(year);
        }
    }
}
```

But I know my algorithm is wrong. As the image include shows my output:

[image]

Comment: Change `Population` and everything else except `year` to a double. You're coercing everything to int at every step, which will affect the results.

Comment: yes, the output is the same though...

Comment: You are adding deceased rather than subtracting it

Comment: I tried that also, born - deceased. I agree that I learn to debug :)

Comment: **[Using the free, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**  Console.WriteLine or MessageBox are not debugging tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is in this line

```
Population = influx - emigrated + born + deceased;
```

You are changing the initial value 26000 to the result of that expression, and the expression itself is wrong because you add the decesead insted of subtracting them.
So let's change the expression to

```
int difference = (born + influx) - (emigrated + deceased);
```

Now we change everywhere the *Population* variable to the *difference* one while we use the *Population* variable to keep the running total of the calc.

```
if (difference > 0)
    Console.WriteLine($"Current Population increases each year  by: {difference}");
else
    Console.WriteLine($"Current Population decreases each year by: {difference}");
Console.WriteLine("__________________________________________");

for (int startYear = 2019 + 1; startYear <= endYear; startYear++)
{
    Population += difference;
    Console.WriteLine($"Population for year {startYear} is: {Population}");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Also, with the current constants used in the expression the result of the expression is always 1 so the results are 26001 for the first year, 26002 for the second year and so on....

Comment: Thanks, now its working, I should have done proper maths, first one part, then subtracting the other part and naturally have that value in a diff variable for each year.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues.

1. You added `deceased`
2. You modified the population to be the difference
3. From your spec the change will be different each year as it changes by a % of the current value.

   ```
   public void CalcPopulation(int endYear) {

     for (int startYear = 2019+1; startYear <= endYear; startYear++) {
       int born = (int)(0.007 * Population);
       int deceased = (int)(0.006 * Population);
       int change = (influx - emigrated) + (born - deceased);
       Population = Population + change;
       Console.WriteLine($"Population for year {startYear} is: {TotalPopulation} {change < 0 ? "increased" : "decreased"} by {Math.Abs(change)}");
       Console.WriteLine();
     }
   }
   ```

I've added the brackets simply for clarity, not actually needed